# Unable to Get Blob using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have been trying to GET Blob using the script below but it gives an error highlighted below. I am using the script from this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4cae25b9-e6ab-4c6e-8269-03cd9ce54ebe/blob-storage-rest-api-generating-authorisation-header-in-powershell-is-going-wrong-somewhere?forum=windowsazuredata) and the $signatureString is used according to the this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194481/azure-rest-api-create-container-net-client-profile-403-forbidden-the-mac-sig). In a way, what i understand from [technet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key) that the authorization header should have the following

## Convert the PS data to JSON

$json = $authHeader | ConvertTo-Json

```
$method = "GET"
$headerDate = (get-date -format r).ToString()
$headers = @{"x-ms-version"="$headerDate"}
$StorageAccountName = ""
$StorageContainerName = "users"
$StorageAccountKey = ""
$Url = "https://$StorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/$StorageContainerName/******/*****.rdp"
$body = "Hello world"
$xmsdate = (get-date -format r).ToString()
$headers.Add("x-ms-date",$xmsdate)
$contentLength = $body.Length
$headers.Add("Content-Length","$contentLength")
$headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type","BlockBlob")
$contentType = "application/json"
#$headers.Add("Content-Type","$contentType")

$signatureString = "$method$([char]10)$([char]10)$([char]10)$contentLength$([char]10)$([char]10)$([char]10)$([char]10)$([char]10)$([char]10)$([char]10)$([char]10)$([char]10)"
#Add CanonicalizedHeaders
$signatureString += "x-ms-blob-type:" + $headers["x-ms-blob-type"] + "$([char]10)"
$signatureString += "x-ms-date:" + $headers["x-ms-date"] + "$([char]10)"
$signatureString += "x-ms-version:" + $headers["x-ms-version"] + "$([char]10)"
#Add CanonicalizedResource
$uri = New-Object System.Uri -ArgumentList $url
$signatureString += "/" + $StorageAccountName + $uri.AbsolutePath + $([char]10) + "restype:container"

$dataToMac = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($signatureString)

$accountKeyBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($StorageAccountKey)

$hmac = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256((,$accountKeyBytes))
$signature = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($hmac.ComputeHash($dataToMac))

$headers.Add("Authorization", "SharedKey " + $StorageAccountName + ":" + $signature);
write-host -fore green $signatureString
write-host -fore green $headers
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method $method -headers $headers
```

Please someone assist me on this.

I am sorry! yes it was not that descriptive. here is the screenshot

[InvalidHeaderValue-Incorrect format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErsC2.png)

I am actually trying to access azure blob storage using powerShell. today, i tried other script to do the same but I get a different error, please see the script and screenshot of that error message below.

```
$storageAccount = ""
```

$accesskey = ""

```
$version = "2017-04-17"
$resource = "tets"
$table_url = "https://$storageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/$resource"
$GMTTime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().toString('R')
$stringToSign = "$GMTTime`n/$storageAccount/$resource"
$hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmacsha.key = [Convert]::FromBase64String($accesskey)
$signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($stringToSign))
$signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)
$headers = @{
    'x-ms-date'    = $GMTTime
    Authorization  = "SharedKeyLite " + $storageAccount + ":" + $signature
    "x-ms-version" = $version
    Accept         = "application/json;odata=fullmetadata"
}
$item = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $table_url -Headers $headers -ContentType application/json
return $item.value
```

Here is the error message I get.
[AuthenticationFailedServer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTnGX.png)

Comment: Its not clear for me what error you get. You say its highlighter but i cant see anything being highlighted. I think your question can be improved somewhat and that will make it easier for StackOverflow users to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Azure PowerShell modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-powershell) to access blobs rather than raw API requests. All of the authentication details should be handled for you already.

Comment: thanks for your response but using PS module will not solve my purpose and that's the reason I opted to go in this way.